# How to call instance of different class from child class?

Tags: python

Here is the code I am working on:

```
from html import *
class Form(BlockContainer):
    def __init__(self, form):
        name = 'form'
        BlockContainer.__init__(self, name)
        self.addAttr('method', 'post')
        self.addAttr('action', form)

class Label(Container):
    def __init__(self, label):
        name = 'label'
        Container.__init__(self, name)
        self.addAttr('for', label)

class Input(Tag):
    def __init__(self, text, title):
        name = 'input'
        Tag.__init__(self, name)
        self.addAttr('type', text)
        self.addAttr('name', title)

class Box(Div):
    def __init__(self, text):
        Div.__init__(self)
        self.addAttr('class', 'box')
        self.addText(text)

class StatusBox(Box):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Box.__init__(self, name)
```

Okay, so I am trying to call the classes Input, Label, and Form from within the class StatusBox. I have tried calling them like this:

```
Class StatusBox(Box):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Box.__init__(self, name)
        Form('blahblablah')
        Label('okiedokie')
        Input('whatever','okay')
```

But when I call them like this, I get nothing. I construct these classes from the shell and they work as intended...

Okay, so from the shell, Form should return this:

```
    t = Form('/savedata')
    # t renders as: '\n<form method="post" action="/savedata" />'
```

so how do I get this returned in StatusBox class?
If I assign to a variable and then return, I get an error 'constructor should return NONE'

Comment: Of course this returns something, the newly constructed instances.

Answer (score 2):

Your instances get constructed, then immediately thrown away, because they are not stored in a variable.

Comment: These questions are so basic, you should read a good tutorial about Python programming, here are some suggestions: http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers